# Access query error ("syntax error in from clause")

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

```
$consulta3 = "SELECT * FROM Dept INNER JOIN Userinfo INNER JOIN Checkinout
                     on Dept.DeptName = '$departamento'
                     where Dept.Deptid = Userinfo.Deptid AND Userinfo.Name = Checkinout.name";
```

the thing im trying to do with this query is: i have a table called Dept where it has all the deparments names and ids, User info that has user name, a department id and a id. Also i have a 3rd table called checkinout that has user id, with a time.

So i want (using the deparment's name) to bring all the data from the Checkinout table from the people that belongs to that deparment, but when i try that query it gives me an error:

```
syntax error in from clause. sql state 37000 in sqlexecdirect
```

and i cant solve it. Im using a Acces Data base.

Thank you very much for you help.

Comment: your missing an on clause in the first join ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access absolutely requires parentheses in the `FROM` clause of any query which includes more that one join.  If you have Access available, create and test a new query in the query designer.  One of the reasons the designer is useful is that it knows the rules for parentheses which keep the db engine happy.

Start with a query similar to this.  Don't worry about filtering based on `Dept.DeptName` at this point.  Just make sure the joins are set up correctly.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM
    (Dept
    INNER JOIN Userinfo
    ON Dept.Deptid = Userinfo.Deptid)
    INNER JOIN Checkinout
    ON Userinfo.Name = Checkinout.name
```

After you have the joins set up correctly, add in your filter constraint (`WHERE Dept.DeptName ...`).

Comment: its not working for me:   "SELECT * FROM
      (Dept INNER JOIN Userinfo
      ON Dept.Deptid = Userinfo.Deptid)
      INNER JOIN Checkinout
      ON Userinfo.Name = Checkinout.name
      where Dept.Name= '$departamento' "

Comment: Does it work without the `WHERE` clause when tested within an Access application session?

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be :

```
SELECT * FROM (Dept 
INNER JOIN Userinfo ON (Dept.Deptid = Userinfo.Deptid)) 
INNER JOIN Checkinout ON (Userinfo.Name = Checkinout.name)
WHERE Dept.DeptName = '$departamento'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have reversed the inner join and where clauses.
You should write the SQL like this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Dept 
 INNER JOIN Userinfo ON Dept.Deptid = Userinfo.Deptid
 INNER JOIN Checkinout ON Userinfo.Name = Checkinout.name"
 WHERE Dept.DeptName = '$departamento'
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably should be:

```
SELECT * FROM Dept 
INNER JOIN Userinfo ON Dept.Deptid = Userinfo.Deptid 
INNER JOIN Checkinout on Userinfo.Name = Checkinout.name 
where Dept.DeptName = '$departamento'
```

Answer (score 0):

what i decided to do is to use 2 different queries:

```
$consulta=  "SELECT * FROM Dept INNER JOIN Userinfo 
         ON Userinfo.Deptid = Dept.Deptid
         where Dept.DeptName = '$departamento'";
```

and

```
$consulta2 = "SELECT  *  FROM Checkinout, Userinfo
    where Checkinout.Userid = '$userid' AND  Userinfo.userid = '$userid' AND 
    Checkinout.Checktime BETWEEN CDate('$fecha1') AND CDate('$fecha2')";
```

The first one to select all the people that belong to one deparment, and the second one to find all the INs and OUTs of one person. Both in a while to be able to look each register of the first result and check with the other query

---

still have problems with the search, its not working fine, im trying to do a full query where it searchs in the 3 tables at the same time but its giving me a error:

```
$toda_consulta= "SELECT * 
                     FROM Dept 
                     INNER JOIN Userinfo ON (Dept.Deptid = Userinfo.Deptid)
                     INNER JOIN Checkinout ON (Checkinout.Userid = Userinfo.Userid)
                     WHERE Dept.DeptName = '$departamento' AND 
                           Checkinout.Checktime BETWEEN CDate('$fecha_inicio') AND CDate('$fecha_fin')";
```

error: `Warning: odbc_exec() [function.odbc-exec]: SQL error: [Microsoft][Controlador ODBC Microsoft Access] sintax error (missing operator) in the expression '(Dept.Deptid = Userinfo.Deptid) INNER JOIN Checkinout ON (Checkinout.Userid = Userinfo.Userid)'., SQL state 37000 in SQLExecDirect in C:\wamp\www\casa 7-9-13\calcula_departamento1.php on line 51`

than you for your help

Comment: If this is the approach that ultimately solved your problem then you should [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) this answer. (It's okay to accept your own answer.)

Comment: You need extra parentheses in the `FROM` clause because it includes more than one join.  See my answer for an example.