# Syntax error in FROM clause. in Inserting records from ms access into another ms access database

Tags: c#, ms-access

This is my code

```
string stR = "INSERT INTO CHECKINOUT (USERID,CHECKTIME,CHECKTYPE,VERIFYCODE,SENSORID,WorkCode) " +
                            " SELECT a.USERID,c.CHECKTIME,c.CHECKTYPE,c.VERIFYCODE,c.SENSORID,c.WorkCode " +
                            " FROM USERINFO a " +
                            " JOIN [MS Access;DATABASE=" + open.FileName + "].USERINFO b " +
                            " ON a.BadgeNumber=b.Badgenumber " +
                            " JOIN [MS Access;DATABASE=" + open.FileName + "].CHECKINOUT c " +
                            " ON  b.USERID=c.USERID " +
                            " WHERE NOT EXISTS " +
                            " (SELECT a.USERID,c.CHECKTIME,c.CHECKTYPE,c.VERIFYCODE,c.SENSORID,c.WorkCode " +
                            " FROM USERINFO a " +
                            " JOIN [MS Access;DATABASE=" + open.FileName + "].USERINFO b " +
                            " ON a.BadgeNumber=b.Badgenumber " +
                            " JOIN [MS Access;DATABASE=" + open.FileName + "].CHECKINOUT c " +
                            " ON  b.USERID=c.USERID)";
```

I got exception error  "Syntax error in FROM clause"

Note: I already exported all ms access tables to ms sql 2000 database and this script is working fine with no error, but with ms access I receive this kind of error, This is the first time I'm using ms access as back end, this is an old program in my office that I need to fix error.

Comment: I guess the join syntax is slightly different in access as compared with SQL Server. It need "Inner" and "Outer" keywords for joining. You may check this by creating a SQL in Access Query designer and check how its syntax generating these queries

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/18968078/20371

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access query error ("syntax error in from clause")](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18967627/access-query-error-syntax-error-in-from-clause)

Answer (score 0):

My first question is which FROM clause is failing.  I would test each portion separately.  Does the query work if you remove the WHERE NOT EXISTS clause?  If so then the problem is in the subquery WHERE NOT EXISTS is referencing.